# Access Memory Target in NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

Lets say I have the following in my nlog.config (taken from http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_MemoryTarget.htm):

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <targets>
         <target name="memory" xsi:type="Memory" layout="${message}" />
     </targets>

     <rules>
         <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="memory" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

How do I access this target programatically?  I am trying to display the logs in a text box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly the same issue here, this worked for me:

```
var target =(MemoryTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("memory");
var log = string.Join("\r\n", target.Logs);
txtLog.Text = log;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use LoggingConfiguration.FindTargetByName passing in the name of the target, then cast it to MemoryTarget, and use the Log property to get the logs gathered

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own target and process log entries as need: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

Comment: Why would he need to do that when NLog has a `MemoryTarget` already written for just this purpose?

Comment: With MemoryTarget you have to check manually/periodically for new log entries. Furthermore, maybe you have to filter leg entries which are already presented, or change the entire TextBox content, which is not very effective. With a custom target, you can notify a listener which can handle added log entries as required - append to the TextBox in that case! After all, it is just an alternative, but I do not agree with the downvote...

Comment: You were probably downvoted because you didn't answer the OPs very specific question.  "How do I access this target programatically?"  The answer isn't how to create a different kind of target.

Answer (score 1):

Check here NLog manual http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Targets_MemoryTarget.htm

```
 using System;

 using NLog;
 using NLog.Targets;

 class Example
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        MemoryTarget target = new MemoryTarget();
        target.Layout = "${message}";
        //  target.Layout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${logger} ${message}";
        NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Debug);

        Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
        logger.Debug("log message");

        foreach (string s in target.Logs)
        {
            Console.Write("logged: {0}", s);
        }
    }
}
```