# Synchronize access to memory log

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, nlog

I have a NLog memory target like [described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23834330/480982).

My application processes the log messages itself:

```
var target = (MemoryTarget) LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("memory");
IList<LogEntry> entries = target.Logs.Select(ParseLogEntry).ToList();
target.Logs.Clear();
...
```

However, from time to time, I get an `InvalidOperationException`, since a log entry arrives just when I am processing it.

Since this is multithreading, I know I need to synchronize access to the collection. In order to do so, I need to use a `lock` statement on something where NLog also uses `lock`. Does such a lock-object exist in NLog?

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706119/how-thread-safe-is-nlog